# Python Pandas search for strings with metacharacters

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have a DataFrame as below:

```
  index       Name            Value
    0       j_smith[1]         32
    1       j_smith[32]        46
    2       r_lee[2]           52
    3       m_brent[3]         61
    4       j_perry[4]         75
    5       j_perry[6]         81
    6       j[3]               92
    7       j[4]               72
    8       r[4]               63
    9       m_jackson[3]       78
    10      r_j[11]            98
```

In the dataframe, the names are formatted as

```
'first name initial'_'last name'[numbers] 
'first name initial'[Numbers]
'first name initial'_'last name initial'[Numbers]
```

I tried to use the `pd.str.contains` function to find the rows with 'j_perry' and 'j'(not item with r_j) as below:

```
Score = DF[DF['Name'].str.contains('j_perry[\d+]|j[\d+]')]
```

I got nothing from Score DataFrame. I think the problem is from the metacharacters: [ ]. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply escape the `[` and `]` characters using `\`:

```
Score = DF[DF['Name'].str.contains('j_perry\[\d+\]|j\[\d+\]')]

>>> Score
    index        Name  Value
4       4  j_perry[4]     75
5       5  j_perry[6]     81
6       6        j[3]     92
7       7        j[4]     72
10     10     r_j[11]     98
```

To make sure you don't get `r_j`, use the `^` to specify that your string needs to start with `j`:

```
Score = DF[DF['Name'].str.contains('^j_perry\[\d+\]|^j\[\d+\]')]

>>> Score
   index        Name  Value
4      4  j_perry[4]     75
5      5  j_perry[6]     81
6      6        j[3]     92
7      7        j[4]     72
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape those chars with special meaning in regex:

```
In [41]: DF[DF['Name'].str.contains(r'^(?:j_perry\[\d+\]|j\[\d+\])')]

Out[41]: 
             Name  Value
index                   
4      j_perry[4]     75
5      j_perry[6]     81
6            j[3]     92
7            j[4]     72
```